# Can't get the CenterX and CenterY of nTh item on recyclerView

Tags: android

is there a way to get the centerX and centerY of Third item on recyclerview

i used

```
 public static Point getViewCenterCoordinatesOnScreen(View myView) {
        int[] location = new int[2];
        myView.getLocationInWindow(location);
        return new Point(location[0]/2, location[1]/2);
    }
```

and it's not working properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working properly"? Please explain what happens and what should have happened.

Comment: `View#getLocationInWindow()` works just fine - did you read its javadocs? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: yes i used it but it doesn't give the exact center of the third item on the list .

Comment: the docs say: `"Computes the coordinates of this view in its window. The argument must be an array of two integers. After the method returns, the array contains the x and y location in that order."` - `x` and `y` location means top-left corner - it has nothing to do with the "center" of the view

Comment: yes i already tried this but what i need is get the center x and center y of an item in a listview !.

Comment: so if you know left-top corner and the wdith and height of your view, then whats the problem with getting the center point?

Answer (score 0):

The location returned is the 0,0 of the view you do ask, the center of it is not the location divided by 2, the correct:

```
public static Point getViewCenterCoordinatesOnScreen(View myView) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    myView.getLocationInWindow(location);
    return new Point(location[0] + (myView.getWidth() / 2), location[1] + (myView.getHeight() / 2));
}
```